# Why must we borrow the type and not the name of the variable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, ampersand

In the following code:

```rust
struct Book {
    pages: i32,
    rating: i32,
}

fn display_page_count(book: &Book) {
    println!("Pages = {:?}", book.pages);
}

fn display_rating(book: &Book) {
    println!("Rating = {:?}", book.rating);
}

fn main() {
    let book = Book {
    pages: 5,
    rating: 9,
    };
    display_page_count(&book);
    display_rating(&book);
}
```

Why do we write `fn display_page_count(book: &Book)` and not `fn display_page_count(&book: Book)`? For me, `book` is the data we’ll want to borrow later, `Book` is just a type (a `struct` here), so I don’t understand why we have to borrow the type and not the variable or parameter. Can someone tell me why I’m wrong?

Comment: It is telling you that it is type "borrowed book" as opposed to type "mutably borrowed book" or type "owned book"

Comment: cause `&Book` is a type too

Comment: The borrow semantics are implemented directly in the type checker. `&Book` is a different type than `Book`.

Comment: the left side of `:` i.e. `book` is the name of the parameter, the right side , i.e. `&Book` is the type

Comment: So @ChrisWelton and @SilvioMayolo you’re saying that by writing `&Book` instead of `Book`, I’m telling the compiler that the struct `Book` is borrowable?

Comment: @guillaume8375 imo that's almost exactly backwards. fn display_page_count(book: &Book) is telling the compiler that the book is borrowed. display_page_count(&book) is telling display_page_count to borrow the book. Pretty much everything in rust is "borrowable".

Comment: `Book` is a thing you own. `&Book` is a thing you're borrowing. `&mut Book` is a thing you're borrowing mutably. They're three different types, in the same way that `Book` and `Box<Book>` are different types that, at their core, provide access to a book in some way or another.

Comment: @guillaume8375 so main() creates the book, and therefore by default owns the book. It lets `display_page_count` and `display_rating` borrow the book in turn, but the lack of `mut`  tells them they can't scribble in the book. `book: &mut Book` would still be borrowing, but you are giving them express permission to scribble. But all that time main() still OWNS the book. When the scope that owns a struct 'ceases to be' the struct is dealloc'd too (although advanced lifetimes can complicate this).. That is how rust works without malloc, garbage collection or reference counts.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWelton, I understand a little bit more why my first comment was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fn display_rating(book: &Book)` declaration, the `book` is the name of the variable that has the type `&Book`.

Using the `fn display_rating(book: Book)` notation would mean that the ownership is passed down to the function and without returning it, it could not be used in the outer scope.

The `book: &Book` means that we are using the reference to the variable. And in this case `book` could have any name you want because it's just the name of the variable with type `&Book`.

Comment: To complement: think of `&T` as `Ref<'_, T>`, it's just so common and such a fundamental concept that it gets its own syntax. So `book: &Book` ~ `book: Ref<'_, Book>`, aka a completely different type to `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is to declare a variable's name and not to tag a type.

When declaring, all variables must be pure names, names cannot be references.

The situation of `&` and `& mut` tag before a variable, is just to tag the variable's type, not the name.

This is because you just gave an object a name. It is the object's type that changes, not the name.